# submission with required textarea is blocked when the value update with append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, required

```js
function addValue() {
  var textarea = $("#textarea");
  textarea.append("text");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form type='post'>
  <textarea id='textarea' readonly required></textarea>
  <input type='button' onclick='addValue()' value='add value to textarea' />
  <input type='submit' value='submit' />
</form>
```

when I click the 'add value to textarea' button to add value to textarea, then I try to submit, it block me from submit with the textarea is required.

what is the problem on it? is that jquery append function does not update the checkValidity? or it is a bug? or is it a browser problem(I am using MicrosoftEdge to test)?

Comment: How are you validating it? I added your code to a snippet which seems to work fine

Comment: I try to click once submit, then add text and submit again

Answer (score 1):

use `val()` instead of `append()`

```
function addValue() {
  $("#textarea").val("text");
}
```

`append()` adds the text or html inside the tag, while `val()` sets the value of input or textarea